# linear regression scatter plot

Tags: r, regression

[image]

I mm investigating a linear relationship between two variables in R. Does the below image look linear or should it be transformed? When I do a log transform it looks pretty much the same. Any suggestions or insights would be appreciated. The R-squared value is 0.03 highest, when I added log transformations on both sides,

Comment: The data are perhaps adult heights (in cm?) and chest diameters? (in inches?). Whatever, a plot of log $y$ versus $y$ and a plot of log $x$ versus $x$ will show only slight curvature so the logarithm doesn't change much, as you say, consistent with relative range $=$ maximum / minimum of about 1.35 (198/147) for $x$ and about 1.6 (35/22) for $y$. The closer the relative range is to 1, the closer the logarithm is to linear. That said, logarithms of both sides is consistent with fitting a power function $y = ax^b$, which has often been found useful in morphometry of organisms. Your call, still.

Comment: I am surprised that $R^2$ is only 0.03. I would have guessed at more.

Comment: Did you fit it with an intercept? It looks very odd that R square is only 0.03